# docker pipeline in jenkins issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run the docker steps using docker pipeline plugin in Jenkins but facing the following issue:

> Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline/java"): error=7, Argument list too long

This issue is coming while running:

```
app = docker.build('java:1.7')
```

I went through the plugin code and seems to be a shell issue where the argument length exceeds the default limit.

Earlier it was working fine but all of sudden start facing this issue.

I appreciate any kind of help here.

Environment details are as follows:
Jenkins Version: 2.89.2 running on AWS RHEL EC2 instance
Docker pipeline plugin version: 1.14

Thanks,
Sanjiv